# Elastic Search how to get the Total Avg of all percentile values in buckets of Date Histogram Agg

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query for a date histogram agg containing 95 percentile aggs of latency values for interval (eg 1 month).

With the query I can get the week buckets with percentile. I would like to get an avg of all percentiles in the buckets.

The Query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "2019-04-03 10:35:04 UTC",
            "lte": "2019-05-01 10:35:04 UTC"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "weeks_avg": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "7d",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "week": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "value",
            "percents": [
              95
            ],
            "hdr": {
              "number_of_significant_value_digits": 3
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The current response I'm getting:

```
 "aggregations":{
      "weeks_avg":{
         "buckets":[
            {
               "key_as_string":"2019-03-28 00:00:00 UTC",
               "key":1553731200000,
               "doc_count":147,
               "week":{
                  "values":{
                     "95.0":24.0078125
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string":"2019-04-04 00:00:00 UTC",
               "key":1554336000000,
               "doc_count":1815,
               "week":{
                  "values":{
                     "95.0":23.0078125
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string":"2019-04-11 00:00:00 UTC",
               "key":1554940800000,
               "doc_count":1821,
               "week":{
                  "values":{
                     "95.0":22.0078125
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string":"2019-04-18 00:00:00 UTC",
               "key":1555545600000,
               "doc_count":1815,
               "week":{
                  "values":{
                     "95.0":22.0078125
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string":"2019-04-25 00:00:00 UTC",
               "key":1556150400000,
               "doc_count":1671,
               "week":{
                  "values":{
                     "95.0":24.0078125
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Do I need to create another Agg to calculate the AVG value of these 5 buckets? In other words do something like this:

**totalPercentileAvg** = (week1.percentileValue  + week2.percentileValue + week3.percentileValue  + week4.percentileValue) / 4;

I'm a little bit confused as already got many syntax errors trying.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both 95 and avg you can specify them separately:

```
 ...
 "aggs": {
    "weeks_avg": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "7d",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "week": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "value",
            "percents": [
              95
            ],
            "hdr": {
              "number_of_significant_value_digits": 3
            }
          }
        },
        "week_avg" : {
          "avg": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

EDIT:
To get the average of 95% values:

```
 ...
 "aggs": {
    "weeks_avg": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "7d",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "week": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "value",
            "percents": [
              95
            ],
            "hdr": {
              "number_of_significant_value_digits": 3
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "avg_weekly_value": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "weeks_avg>week.95" 
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think I could not elaborate properly my question. I'm looking for the Total Avg of all percentiles. I've edited my question to be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Then you need to run a pipeline aggregation.

Comment: @sandroka I updated the answer, it does what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful here - make sure you understand what the statistics you are getting tell you. And hide from you. Lets imagine you are looking at performance in some way, e.g. a database response time measured in ms.  Lower is better.

You characterised the ask this as

totalPercentileAvg = (week1.percentileValue + week2.percentileValue + week3.percentileValue + week4.percentileValue) / 4;

First, what's wrong why just taking the percentileValue calculated over the 4 weeks as a whole if you are trying to summarise the entire 4 period into a single number?

I am unconvinced as to the value of splitting this arbitrarily into 4 numbers, then taking the average of these 4?  Lets imagine you had 3 good weeks, with low volume, and one bad week, with greater volume.  On good weeks you percentileValue was 400. On the bad week it was 800.  The average here is 500ms, which seems OK.  But maybe the volume on the bad week was 10x that on the 3 good weeks, and your customers had a slow experience, but your stat misses this almost entirely.

(The data you quoted had almost exactly a 10:1 ratio in hits between one week and another)